# Ui-Router and Firebase: handle user $stateParam change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angular-ui-router, angularfire

part of my application is a blog. I simply want to redirect the user when he changes the URL param `$stateParam`. 
I'm using `Firebase` in a service:

```js
angular.module('myApp')
       .factory('CrudFactory', ['CrudService', '$state', function (CrudService, $stat) {

            var Crud  = function () {

                CrudService.apply(this, arguments);

            };

            Crud.prototype.loadData = function (recordKey) {

                var datas =  this.firebaseObject(this.ref.child(recordKey));

                datas.$loaded().then(function(data) {
                    
                    console.log(data);
                
                }).catch(function(error){
                  
                    console.log(error);
                });
                
              return datas;
            };

            return Crud;

        }]);

/*post.controller.js file*/
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('PostCtrl',['$scope','$stateParams','CrudFactory', function ($scope, $stateParams,CrudFactory) {

        var crud = new CrudFactory('posts');

        $scope.data = crud.loadData($stateParams.postId);
    }]);

/*index.js file*/

angular.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {

        $stateProvider.state('post', {

              url:'/blog/:postId',
              templateUrl:'app/blog/posts/post.single.html',
              controller:'PostCtrl'

              })
        

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  

    }]);
```

$firebaseObject's `$loaded`returns a promise; when the user alters the URL parameter, the `loadData` method returns the `$firebaseObject` but without the stored datas causing the promise to resolve anyway.

I'd like to reject the promise to be able to use `UI-router's resolve statement` thus redirecting the user but I wasn't able to achieve it. 
I've already tried to access `$firebaseObject` properties and evaluate them but I'm stuck.
Does anyone have a clue? Thank you guys

Comment: This is pretty unclear. There is no promise being returned anywhere that could be resolved/rejected? The only promise in your code is being used to console.log. I think you want to return $loaded() from Crud.prototype.loadData(). Also, for all that is pure and good in the universe, don't put Firebase into something called CrudFactory :(  CRUD defeats all the awesome that is real-time.

Comment: @Kato sorry for the lack of clarity, I was talking about the promise returned by `$loaded`. I think I'll compare the value returned and redirect the user. @FirebaseTeam: no offense, Firebase is an awesome tool ;)